# Which methods of java.nio.file.Files follow symbolic links and which don't?

Tags: java, symlink, symlink-traversal

The Java helper class `java.nio.file.Files` has methods to access file attributes. Some of the class methods follow symbolic links (all methods with a `LinkOption` parameter), while for some other methods it is not clear wether symbolic links are followed or not (methods without `LinkOption` parameter).

These are some methods that follow symbolic links:

- `Files.isDirectory(Path, LinkOption...)`
- `Files.isRegular(Path, LinkOption...)`
- `Files.getAttribute(Path, String, LinkOption...)`
- `Files.getLastModified(Path, LinkOption...)`
- `Files.getOwner(Path, LinkOption...)`
- `Files.getPosixFilePermission(Path, LinkOption...)`

For some other methods, it is no obvious to determine if they follow symbolic links or not (no `LinkOption...` parameter and no mention of symbolic links in the javadoc) :

- `Files.isSymbolicLink(Path)`
- `Files.isExecutable(Path)`
- `Files.isReadable(Path)`
- `Files.isWritable(Path)`
- `Files.isHidden(Path)`
- `Files.size(Path)`
- `Files.getFileStore(Path)`

Which are the methods without `LinkOption...` parameter that follow symbolic links, and why ?

Comment: Generally speaking, on Unix systems unless you're explicitly inspecting a symbolic link, it gets followed transparently.

Comment: This question could also have asked whether `newDirectoryStream` follows links. I’d be curious to know.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: in most cases this seems to a `FileSystemProvider` implementation choice to follow symbolic links or not (this may answers the "why" question). Symbolic links are:

Followed:

- `Files.size(Path)`

Mostly followed:

- `Files.getFileStore(Path)` : followed on Windows and Linux, not followed on Jimfs

Not followed:

- `Files.isSymbolic(Path)`

Mostly not followed:

- `Files.isExecutable(Path)` : not followed on Windows and Unix, but followed on Jimfs
- `Files.isReadable(Path)` : not followed on Windows and Unix, but followed on Jimfs

Fully implementation specific:

- `Files.isWritable(Path)` : followed on Windows but not on Unix
- `Files.isHidden(Path)` : followed on Windows but not on Unix

You can be sure about whether symbolic links are followed or not by calling `Files.readAttributes(Path, Class, LinkOption...)` and using the returned attributes.

## `Files.isSymbolic(Path)` does not follow symbolic links

For `Files.isSymbolic(Path)`, the reason is obvious: if the method had followed the symbolic links by default, it would have always returned `false`.

## `Files.isHidden(Path)` follow symbolic links on Windows but not on Unix

From the method signature, we may think that the method does not follow symbolic links (because there is no `LinkOption...` parameter). However, this is not so evident.

The `Files.isHidden(Path)` method delegate to the implementation of the `java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.isHidden(Path)` and the javadoc does not specify wether the method follows symbolic links or not.

On Windows, it is [implemented by following symbolic links](https://zgrepcode.com/java/openjdk/10.0.2/java.base/sun/nio/fs/windowsfilesystemprovider.java), see line 465 (the `true` parameter in `WindowsFileAttributes.get(file, true)` call tells to follow symbolic links):

```
@Override
public boolean isHidden(Path obj) throws IOException { 
    WindowsPath file = WindowsPath.toWindowsPath(obj); 
    file.checkRead(); 
    WindowsFileAttributes attrs = null; 
    try { 
        attrs = WindowsFileAttributes.get(file, true); 
    } catch (WindowsException x) { 
        x.rethrowAsIOException(file); 
    } 
    // DOS hidden attribute not meaningful when set on directories 
    if (attrs.isDirectory()) 
        return false; 
    return attrs.isHidden(); 
}
```

On Unix, this method is [implemented without following symbolic links](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/solaris/classes/sun/nio/fs/UnixFileSystemProvider.java) (it only checks that the file starts with a "."):

```
@Override
public boolean isHidden(Path obj) {
    UnixPath file = UnixPath.toUnixPath(obj);
    file.checkRead();
    UnixPath name = file.getFileName();
    if (name == null)
        return false;
    return (name.asByteArray()[0] == '.');
}
```

Thus, we can conclude that this is implementation specific.

## `Files.isExecutable(Path)` don't follow symbolic links in most file-systems

This method delegate to `Files.isAccessible(Path, AccessMode.EXECUTE)`, which delegates to the `FileSystemProvider.checkAccess(Path, AccessMode...)` method.

On Windows, the `WindowsFileSystemProvider.checkAccess(Path, AccessMode...)` method delegates to the `java.lang.SecurityManager` which decides whether the file is executable or not. AFAIK, the `SecurityManager` does not follow symbolic links, so we can assume that `Files.isExecutable(Path)` does not follow symbolic links on Windows.

On Unix, the `UnixFileSystemProvider.checkAccess(Path, AccessMode...)` method also delegates to the `SecurityManager`, we can assume that `Files.isExecutable(Path)` does not follow symbolic links on Unix too.

On Jimfs (in-memory file-system from Google), the call delegates to [`com.google.common.jimfs.FileSystemView.checkAccess(JimfsPath)`](https://github.com/google/jimfs/blob/master/jimfs/src/main/java/com/google/common/jimfs/FileSystemView.java) which follows symbolic links (even if Jimfs does not support access control):

```
public void checkAccess(JimfsPath path) throws IOException {
    // just check that the file exists
    lookUpWithLock(path, Options.FOLLOW_LINKS).requireExists(path);
}
```

Thus, we can conclude that `Files.isExecutable(Path)` may follow symbolic links depending on the file-system, but won't in a majority of the cases (Unix+Windows).

## `Files.isReadable(Path)` does not follow symbolic links on most file-systems

The implementation for `Files.isReadable(Path)` is very similar to the one of `isExecutable(Path)` : don't follow links on Unix and Windows, but follow links on Jimfs.

## `Files.isWritable(Path)`

As for `Files.isExecutable(Path)`, the `isWritable(Path)` method delegates to the `FileSystemProvider.checkAccess(Path)`.

On Windows, this requires determining if the file has a read-only attribute, which is done by following links (see `WindowsFileSystemProvider` code above).

On Unix, this is apparently done without following symbolic links (see `UnixFileSystemProvider` above).

Thus, we can conclude that this is implementation specific.

## `Files.size(Path)` follow symbolic links

The implementation delegates to `readAttributes`, thus it follows symbolic links for all file-system implementations:

```
public static long size(Path path) throws IOException {
    return readAttributes(path, BasicFileAttributes.class).size();
}
```

## `Files.getFileStore(Path)`

The method delegates to the `FileSystemProvider.getFileStore(Path)` method.

On Windows, it uses `WindowsFileStore.create(Path)` which follow symbolic links (see `true` parameter):

```
static WindowsFileStore create(WindowsPath file) throws IOException {
    try {
        // if the file is a link then GetVolumePathName returns the
        // volume that the link is on so we need to call it with the
        // final target
        String target = WindowsLinkSupport.getFinalPath(file, true);
  ...
```

On Unix, the `FileSystemProvider.getFileStore(Path)` method is abstract and implemented by subclasses, e.g. `[LinuxFileSystem][3]` :

```
@Override
LinuxFileStore getFileStore(UnixPath path) throws IOException {
    return new LinuxFileStore(path);
```

}

This classes constructs a [`UnixFileStore`](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/solaris/classes/sun/nio/fs/UnixFileStore.java) by getting the attributes with link following (`true` parameter in `UnixFileAttributes.get()` call):

```
private static long devFor(UnixPath file) throws IOException {
    try {
        return UnixFileAttributes.get(file, true).dev();
    } catch (UnixException x) {
        x.rethrowAsIOException(file);
        return 0L;  // keep compiler happy
    }
}
```

In Jimfs, the `FileStore` seems to be attached to the file at creation time, thus, it looks that links are not followed.

Thus, we can conclude that `Files.getFileStore(Path)` uses symbolic link following in most file-system implementations.

Comment: "we can assume that `Files.isExecutable(Path)` does not follow symbolic links on Unix too": Default Unix behavior is to follow links, and I've never seen the Java runtime behave differently. Provide an example, not an assumption, if you're going to claim otherwise.

Comment: @chrylis : in https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/solaris/classes/sun/nio/fs/UnixFileSystemProvider.java, the `checkAccess(Path,AccessMode...)` method apparently does not use symbolic links (the `access(UnixPath,AccessMode)` method from https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/solaris/classes/sun/nio/fs/UnixNativeDispatcher.java has also no mention of symbolic links). Maybe I missed something, but from my analysis, links are not followed for `Files.isExecutable(Path)`. I would be happy to a test case.

Comment: That's because you don't *use* symbolic links when traversing. They just *happen* unless you explicitly `stat` them.

Comment: Also see the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/package-summary.html) of the `java.nio.file` package. “For the most part, symbolic links are transparent to applications and operations on symbolic links are automatically redirected to the target of the link. Exceptions to this are when a symbolic link is deleted or renamed/moved in which case the link is deleted or removed rather than the target of the link. This package includes support for symbolic links where implementations provide these semantics.”